# deployed app showing this "Error: EROFS: read-only file system" while uploading pic on app

Tags: javascript, deployment

I deployed the MERN stack app on cyclic.sh using git-hub, this app has upload pics functionality when I tried to upload pics on the app cyclic.sh log shows:

> Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'uploads/1663056322939--11b.png'

I also deployed the app in Heroku using Heroku-git and its property working, I am able to upload the image

Comment: Something is wrong with the file system of the machines where the app is deployed. Ask the server administrator for help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cyclic provides object storage backed by AWS S3. Each app is provisioned with an S3 bucket and allowed read/write access. So, you need to upload the image to the respective provisioned S3 bucket rather than directly to the server.

To do that first install aws-sdk:

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

Then you can upload the file to the bucket as follows:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json())

// curl -i https://some-app.cyclic.app/myFile.txt
app.get('*', async (req,res) => {
  let filename = req.path.slice(1)

  try {
    let s3File = await s3.getObject({
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
      Key: filename,
    }).promise()

    res.set('Content-type', s3File.ContentType)
    res.send(s3File.Body.toString()).end()
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'NoSuchKey') {
      console.log(`No such key ${filename}`)
      res.sendStatus(404).end()
    } else {
      console.log(error)
      res.sendStatus(500).end()
    }
  }
})


// curl -i -XPUT --data '{"k1":"value 1", "k2": "value 2"}' -H 'Content-type: application/json' https://some-app.cyclic.app/myFile.txt
app.put('*', async (req,res) => {
  let filename = req.path.slice(1)

  console.log(typeof req.body)

  await s3.putObject({
    Body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
    Key: filename,
  }).promise()

  res.set('Content-type', 'text/plain')
  res.send('ok').end()
})

// curl -i -XDELETE https://some-app.cyclic.app/myFile.txt
app.delete('*', async (req,res) => {
  let filename = req.path.slice(1)

  await s3.deleteObject({
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
    Key: filename,
  }).promise()

  res.set('Content-type', 'text/plain')
  res.send('ok').end()
})

// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Catch all handler for all other request.
app.use('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendStatus(404).end()
})

// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`index.js listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

You can refer to Cyclic [docs](https://docs.cyclic.sh/concepts/storage) for more details.